# CORS and Access-Control-Allow-Methods in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have an express application with many routes:

```
app.get('foo/bar', function(res, res, next) { ... });
app.post('foo/bar', function(res, res, next) { ... });
app.get('another/one/path', function(res, res, next) { ... }));
```

And I need to send cross domain AJAX requests to this application. So, I need to send correct Access-Control-Allow-Methods on OPTIONS requests. For example, if the request is `OPTIONS 'foo/bar'`, then the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header should be equal `GET,POST`.
I see that if I send OPTIONS request in Express framework I already get a correct list of methods in response body. For example if I I send `OPTIONS 'foo/bar'` I get a response with body `GET,POST`. Now, I want to send `GET,POST` in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header too. I'm trying to find an easy solution to do this. I don't want to add an options routes, because I already have more than 200 routes in the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS in Express/Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-node-js)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution would be to use [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm package.

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to roll your own, this will get you started.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var oneof = false;
    if (req.headers.origin) { //req.headers.origin.match(/whateverDomainYouWantToWhitelist/g) ) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        oneof = true;
    }
    if (req.headers['access-control-request-method']) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', req.headers['access-control-request-method']);
        oneof = true;
    }
    if (req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
        oneof = true;
    }
    if (oneof) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
    }

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if (oneof && req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```